# HY and IG CDX Indexes

Tags: credit, default

Where can I get a "tradable quote" and daily historical data on CDX.NA.IG and CDX.NA.HY indexes other than Bloomberg.

Comment: By "other than Bloomberg" do you really mean "free" (then I don't know), rather than "Refinitiv" or "IHS Markit"? You can find free last close on https://www.theice.com/cds/MarkitIndices.shtml (note, HY has price here, while it really trades on spread).

Comment: Apoligies, I meant NA.IG has a price, while it's usually quoted on spread. HY, EM trade on price.